# Android Project Creation

Tags: android

How do I create an Android Project with the 2 source files provided in this link?

http://www.rbgrn.net/content/367-source-code-to-multitouch-visible-test

I tried to create a blank project and to add these 2 files but I don't know how to create an activity in this method.

Comment: You realize one of those files is an activity, right?

Comment: Start here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Android Application project. Name it whatever you want and have it create a default activity, but change the name of the activity to "MTVisTestActivity".

Open the file MTVisTestActivity.java and keep the package declaration, but overwrite the rest of the text with the first file text

Create a new class called MTView (right click on src->your.package.name then select New->Class). Open it and paste in the text for the second file - again, just keeping the package name.